# Qt and Pyside6: Why does my Qt signal frequency monitor sometimes report very high values?

Tags: python-3.x, qt

I have some code that monitors the frequency of Qt signals being emitted. This code is defined in the same QObject as the signals being monitored. It also exposes the measured values as properties:

```
def enable_performance_monitoring(self):
    self.__perf_monitoring = True
    self.__monitor_signal(self.pubRequested)
    self.__monitor_signal(self.deserialisedMsg)
    self.__monitor_signal(self.publishedMsg)
    self.__monitor_signal(self.msgReceivedByNode)
    self.__monitor_signal(self.msgSerialised)
    self.__monitor_signal(self.pushToQtQueue)
    self.__monitor_signal(self.msgReceivedByQt)
    self.__monitor_signal(self.msgParsedAndQMLNotified)

def __monitor_signal(self, signal: Signal):
    def signal_callback(signal=signal):
        self.__sig_times_prev[signal] = (
            self.__sig_times[signal] if signal in self.__sig_times else 0
        )
        self.__sig_times[signal] = self.__node.get_clock().now().nanoseconds
    signal.connect(signal_callback)

@average
def __get_frequency_avg(self, signal: Signal) -> float:
    prev = self.__sig_times_prev[signal] if signal in self.__sig_times_prev else 0
    new = self.__sig_times[signal] if signal in self.__sig_times else 0
    dt = new - prev
    if dt == 0: return 0
    return 1 / (dt / 1e9)
```

The decorator is below:

```
def average(wrapped: Callable) -> Callable:
    """
    A decorator that stores the last 100 return values of the function and returns the average.
    """
    last_100 = []

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal last_100
        result = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
        last_100.append(result)
        if len(last_100) > 100:
            last_100.pop(0)
        return sum(last_100) / len(last_100)

    return wrapper
```

The pub requested signal is emitted from a`publish()` function which is called from a loop with a `sleep(1/self.__rate)` in a thread that does nothing else.

```
def publish(self, json_str: str):
    if not self.active:
        return
    self.pubRequested.emit()
    pubtype = self.__pub.msg_type
    msg = deserialise_from_json(json_str, pubtype)
    self.deserialisedMsg.emit()
    self.__pub.publish(msg)
    self.publishedMsg.emit()
```

These signals should all have the same frequency (note, I also am measuring latency between signals).

The `msgReceievedByNode` signal is emitted from a ROS2 thread (seperate from the GUI thread and the publishing thread), because all ros2 subscription callbacks are run from a ros2 executor. It serialises the message and emits the `pushToQtQueue` signal with the message.
This is connected via `self.pushToQtQueue.connect(self.__qt_callback, Qt.QueuedConnection)`

```
# set up test subscription (runs in ros_thread)
def __ros2_callback(self, msg: Any):
    if not self.active:
        return
    self.msgReceivedByNode.emit()
    json_str = serialise_to_json(msg)
    self.msgSerialised.emit()
    if self.__use_mutex:
        self.__mutex.lock()
    self.pushToQtQueue.emit(json_str)
    # self.__pending_msg = json_str

# set up qt callback (runs in qt_thread when queue is popped)
def __qt_callback(self, json_str: str):
    if self.__use_mutex:
        self.__mutex.unlock()
    self.msgReceivedByQt.emit()
    self.__msg: QJSValue = self.__parse_json.call([QJSValue(json_str)])
    self.msgParsedAndQMLNotified.emit(self.__msg)
```

The mutex is there to throttle the rate at which messages are pushed to the qt queue. I receive ros2 messages from 100 topics each at 25Hz, so I did not want to blow up the Qt queue.

I then display this in a Qt QML chart.

The strange thing is, I sometimes see values like 100Hz, sometimes even 400Hz, even though it should be 25Hz maximum. Why would this be happening?

edit: Full code found here: https://codeshare.io/9Og880